# how to reference an external project as a dependent library to Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle

My Dev enviroment as below:

```
Android Studio 3.1.3
Gradle 4.4
```

My workspace struct as below:

```
Workspace
       |_____MyAndroidApp
       |           |_____MyAndroidApp
       |                   |____app
       |                         |____build.gradle              
       |                   |____settings.gradle
       |                   |____build.gradle
       |
       |—————SomeOpenSourceAndroidLib
       |           |____SomeOpenSourceAndroidLib
       |           |     |____build.gradle              
       |           |____settings.gradle
       |           |____build.gradle
```

I want to reference `SomeOpenSourceAndroidLib` in the app project so i add following lines to `settings.gradle` of app project

```
include ':SomeOpenSourceAndroidLib'
project(':SomeOpenSourceAndroidLib').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../../SomeOpenSourceAndroidLib')

dependencies {
      ...
      //implementation project('xxx.xxx:SomeOpenSourceAndroidLib') //SomeOpenSourceAndroidLib is an opensource project, it comiples ok if i use the online version.
      implementation project(':SomeOpenSourceAndroidLib')
}
```

here is what i have verfied:

1. the app project compiles ok if using the online version of SomeOpenSourceAndroidLib
2. the SomeOpenSourceAndroidLib compiles ok
3. the  buildTypes configuration are same

   ```
   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled true
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
       debug {
           minifyEnabled false
       }
   }
   ```
4. "Offline work" setting in the ide is turned off

but i still get these errors:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could
>   not resolve project :sdl_android.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project
>   :sdl_android.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project
>   :sdl_android.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath':
>   Could not resolve project :sdl_android.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project
>   :sdl_android.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem earlier.
Try this

implementation project(path: ':SomeOpenSourceAndroidLib', configuration: 'default')